# How use ProgressDialog and Async Task get Method simultaneously

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have generic async task class which fetches response from server . And i receive those response by using get method . Now i knw that UI thread is block when i use get method , bcoz of which my progress Dialog doesnt showup on time .

Now can someone tell me alternative to do this ?? (In every case i need to send back the response to the activity which has made the call of execute so opening new activity wouldn't help me )

Code :
AsyncTask Class

```
 public class GetDataFromNetwork extends AsyncTask<Void,String,Object> {

protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    progressDialog.show();
} 


 protected Object doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Object result = null;
    try {
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER10);
        new MarshalBase64().register(envelope);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(ipAddress + webService);
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "true");
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(nameSpace + methodName, envelope);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            publishProgress(e.getMessage());
        }
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        System.out.println("response: " + androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
        result = envelope.getResponse();
        if(result!=null){
            System.out.println("GetDataFromNetwork.doInBackground() result expection---------"+result);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("GetDataFromNetwork.doInBackground()-------- Errors");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return result;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Code : Activity

```
GetDataFromNetwork request = new GetDataFromNetwork(
                                        this,
                                        ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER,
                                        getResources().getText(R.string.autenticate).toString());
response= (SoapObject)request.execute().get();
```

Comment: The simplest solution is do not use AsyncTask.get() and process your SoapObject response inside your AsyncTask implementation (either in doInBackground() or onPostExecute())

Comment: @yorkw :Thanks , But ur solution is not possible .For example : my response return me a list which i need for setAdapter() in one the case and sends me a class object another case . so generic processor is not possible :( .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm doing stuff like this all the time in my apps and the easiest way I found was to create "Callback" interface and pass it as a parameter to my "AsyncTask"s. You do your "doInBackground()" processing and when it's finished you call the "Callback" instance from onPostExecute passing the "result" object as parameter.

Below is a very simplified version of it.

Example of Callback interface:

```
package example.app;

public interface Callback {

        void run(Object result);
}
```

Example of AsyncTask using the Callback interface above:

```
public class GetDataFromNetwork extends AsyncTask<Void,String,Object> {
  Callback callback;
  public GetDataFromNetwork(Callback callback){
     this.callback = callback;
  }

   protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      progressDialog.show();
  } 


   protected Object doInBackground(Void... params) {
      Object result = null;
      // do your stuff here
      return result;
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
     callback.run(result);
     progressDialog.dismiss();
  }

}
```

Example of how to use the classes above in your app:

```
class Example {
   public onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      //initialize

      GetDataFromNetwork request = new GetDataFromNetwork(new Callback(){
                     public void run(Object result){
                             //do something here with the result
       }});
       request.execute();      
   }
}
```

Comment: Can u please explain in more detail .

Comment: I'll add some more details to my answer as it's not really gonna fit here.

Comment: Can u please mail me if possible for u , my id is mohit.1.sharma@silverskills.com

Comment: I'll try to write a tutorial on how to do this with some real code example when I have time, but for now I just posted here some simple example code. Hope it helps you. Try adapting that to your code and let me know if it worked :)

Comment: DallaRosa: It helped but please write full code for with progress dialog initialization :)

Answer (score 1):

Like yorkw says, The problem is that you make the UI thread wait for the response with this code:

```
response= (SoapObject)request.execute().get();
```

As the documentation for [AsyncTask.get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) says:

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves
>   its result.

Since the UI thread waits for the response, it can't show a progress dialog. The solution is to move the code that handles the response to the onPostExecute() method:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    // Now we have the response, dismiss the dialog and handle the response
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    response = (SoapObject) result;
}
```

This method will be invoked *after* you have the response. Meanwhile, the UI thread can take care of showing a progress dialog.

Comment: cant have generic processor for response . Secondly , how can i send response processed to my parent activity .

Comment: Then make the code in onPostExecute() depend on what object you received and/or the parameters you configured GetDataFromNetwork with. To return some result to the parent activity, use the usual Activity.startActivityForResult() and Activity.setResult() pattern. It is fine to call Activity.setResult() and Activity.finish() from onPostExecute().

Comment: 1 use AsyncTask<Void,String,SoapObject>.onPostExecute(SoapObject result), 2 the inner class AsyncTask inside your parent activity takes care of everything for you, do your task in background (separate thread), once done, go back and do whatever you want on UI thread. that is why it called AsyncTask, by calling AsyncTask.get() you make it synchronously (ui thread wait doInBackground thread).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't create another class in which you will put response and in there you will have get and set method. Then in onPostExecute you write it with set method and call a handler where you will do whatever you want...This is just an idea... :)

Comment: Thanks Jovan .I already tried that but in that case there is no synchronicity in my code

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the AsyncTask, your UI thread won't be blocked. Are you downloading your data inside `doInBackground()` ? Because that is where you should be doing it.

Comment: yes , i am doing pls see the code(just added that also) . Problem is with .get() Method in activity class.

Comment: Why don't you use a Handler mechanism? When the object is downloaded, send a message to the UI thread.